# PHP upload, file doesnt change using move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, upload

look this code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
```

Is possibile that $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] return same file each time that i try to upload?

In other words , when i try to upload in $target_path i see same file, the one that i had uploaded a week ago.
Also if i try to delete it before to upload, the problem persist:

```
if(file_exists($target_path)) {
chmod($target_path,0777); //Change the file permissions if allowed
$z = unlink($target_path); //remove the file
```

If I change the directory of upload (inside target_path) first time the upload works fine but after , I have same problem, i.e: the file doesnt change.

Thanks

---

EDIT:
This is how i create target_path:

```
$target_path = "uploads/"; //Folder where to save
```

$id_long =  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

$ret = $mysqli->query("Select id from android_udid  WHERE registration_id = '$id_long' ");
$ret = $ret->fetch_object()->id;
$ret.=".jpg";

$target_path = $target_path .$ret ;

Explaining:
I send a photo with my android app, the name of the photo is a registration id.

Because i'm testing my app, the target_path in my test is the same all times, however i chenge the photo to upload, so $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] should be changed , no?

****NEW EDIT ****

If i change 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path) in

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], "xxx.jpg");
first time "xxx.jpg" is the right file, then if i delete it and try again to upload an other file "xxx.jpg" will be the same file of the first upload!!!

* LAST EDIT ****
Ok, the problem was not in php code. Altervista that is my hosting domain had an enabled cache so i saw  the same file, now i have disabled it and all works fine.
I'm sorry about this.

Best Regards.

Enrico

Comment: So you want to delete a file if it exists, rather than creating a new file?

Comment: how are you checking the image? Are you using your web browser to check the image? If yes this could be just a cache issue.

Comment: No, because i am obtaining same file all times, I tried to delete the old one and after move the file just updated in the right directory

Comment: what does $target_path contain? Also, if you can chmod it, you can definitely delete it (unlink), makes that line redundant.

Comment: Have you echo'd out $target_path to see what it contains?

Comment: If your target path is a folder unlink will not delete it. Unlink deletes files.

Comment: It's not, that's why I asked :)

Comment: I just echo'd target_path and its content is right.

Comment: @Edge7 Please answer your own question and accept it so other users can benefit from the problem's cause description.